# What is the value of ζ(1)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

The value of the Riemann-Zeta function at -1, for example, diverges in the partial sums. However, we can atribute the value -1/12 to it. The function value at 1 should be no different: it is also a divergent series; so what's the atributed value to it?

Comment: It's a divergent series that can't be regularised or given a value by analytic continuation so $\zeta$ is undefined there (or given the value of $\infty$). It does have a Cauchy principal value though, $\frac{\zeta(1+\varepsilon)+\zeta(1-\varepsilon)}{2}\sim\gamma$, the Euler-Mascheroni constant. The fact that $\zeta(1)=\infty$ corresponds with the fact that there are infinitely many primes.